# Wix React native navigation tab button goes out of bound on navigating back to screen

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-navigation, wix-react-native-navigation

Pushing to new screen with **tabbarHidden** set to **true** and poping back to the screen, tabbar is animated from the left and it looks sloppy. Is it a bug or there is prop i can pass to prevent it from animating.

Expected behaviour is that Tab bar icons should not animate from left

This code hide tab on push

```
this.props.navigator.push({
  screen: Route.UPLOADS,
  navigatorStyle: {
    tabBarHidden: true
  },
  title: title
})
```

**Bug screen capture**

[image]

**Environment**

- React Native Navigation version: v1.1.493
- React Native version: ^0.56.0
- Platform: iOS
- Device info: iPhone 8, iPhone 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this issue by adding following line to tabstyle

```
tabBarTranslucent: false
```

Another solution is to upgrade the wix navigation library to v2.